# Why won't this code run in PHP 7.0

Tags: php, odbc, mamp, iis-8

I am trying to create a SQL query based on a couple of month and date values I pull directly from the user machine using PHP.

**My problem is, that my code works FINE on my testing server (wampp) yet hangs on the production server (IIS8).**

Basically, I have a few If, then statements comparing variables to other variables, and if the conditions are met, they utilize another particular variable to create a SQL statement.

I have other odbc / php functions that work correctly on this same site, however it is this code and another, similar function that hang the server.

Any help is appreciated.

```php
function tmlySales() { // last year, this month sales   

      include('odbc_connect.php');

      $salesPersonID = $_SESSION['SESS_SAP_ID'];

      $conn=odbc_connect($server,$user,$pass);          

      $m = date('m');

      if($m == 01) {

          $month = 'SSSA10';

          $year = date('Y', strtotime('-1 year'));

      }

      if($m == 02) {

          $month = 'SSSA11';

          $year = date('Y', strtotime('-1 year'));
      }

      if($m == 03) {

          $month = 'SSSA12';

          $year = date('Y', strtotime('-1 year'));

      }

      if($m == 04) {

          $month = 'SSSA01';

          $year = date('Y');

      }

      if($m == 05) {

          $month = 'SSSA02';

          $year = date('Y');

      }

      if($m == 06) {

          $month = 'SSSA03';

          $year = date('Y');

      }

      if($m == 07) {

          $month = 'SSSA04';

          $year = date('Y');

      }

      if($m == 08) {

          $month = 'SSSA05';

          $year = date('Y');

      }

      if($m == 09) {

          $month = 'SSSA06';

          $year = date('Y');

      }

      if($m == 10) {

          $month = 'SSSA07';

          $year = date('Y');

      }

      if($m == 11) {

          $month = 'SSSA08';

          $year = date('Y');

      }

      if($m == 12) {

          $month = 'SSSA09';

          $year = date('Y');

      }

      $sql = "SELECT ".$month." FROM REPSA WHERE SSRP#1=".$salesPersonID." and SSYEAR =".$year."";

      $result = odbc_exec($conn,$sql);

      while($row = odbc_fetch_array($result)) {

          $tmlySales = $row[$month];

          $currency = number_format($tmlySales,2);

          echo '$&nbsp;'.$currency.'';

     }
}
```

Comment: "hangs" is quite broad. What exactly happens? Enable error reporting in PHP and the server itself, check the log files etc. and post them in the question

Comment: Have you looked in your error logs?

Comment: I looked in the error logs on the server and it doesn't give me any good information, I can tell that it is throwing a 500 error, I believe that is internal server error, just don't know why. once i remove this function it seems to be fine. by "hangs" I mean that it displays the very first line of the page which is the declaring the HTML doctype. then nothing after..

Answer (score 0):

Without an error it's quite difficult.
First I would say

```
$m = date('m');
```

returns **a string** not an octal.

Instead of doing:

```
if($m == 02)
```

You should do (see the quotes):

```
  if($m == '02')
```

If you need a better answer, provide more information.

Comment: Thanks, it turns out it is a known bug in PHP 7.0 which is the difference between my development machine and the production server. Turned on error reporting in the production server and the error was something about an octal. Can't remember exactly what, I will try this and see if it works.